# Rails 4 Integer number field returns string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, types, integer

When I enter something into a `number_field` and post the form to the controller, Rails can't save because i have a numericality validation:

```
validates :rating, numericality: { greater_than: 0, less_than: 6 }
```

I debugged the controller by this piece of code:

```
raise "It exploded into pieces!" unless @comment.save
```

The exception I used for debugging said that my `:rating` was a string instead of an integer. Before this, i rendered the json errors for `@comment` and that said that `:rating` was not a number.

These are very useful to spot the problem, but I can't find any solutions to fix the problem. I checked the database schema and it says that `:rating` should be an integer, as in:

```
 t.integer  "rating"
```

I don't know what to do at this point. Can somebody help me? Thank you in advance.

P.S. I use `number_field`.

P.P.S.
In my controller:

```
def ccreate
  @comment = Comment.new(params.permit(:rating, :body, :name, :game_id))
  raise "It exploded into pieces!" unless @comment.save
end
```

In my view:

```
<% if @comments.count < 10 %>
    <%= form_for(comment_path) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :rating %><br>
        <%= f.number_field :rating %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :body %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: So the error from rails said that rating wasn't a number?

Comment: Yes, the exception's "parameters" part said that

Comment: Pass `only_integer: true` inside hash.

Comment: can you restart rails server.. ? Blind guess I did.. :p

Comment: I did that, same results. You are saying the validation hash, right Arslan?

Comment: @avaragecoder Yup, validation hash!

Comment: It gives the same results, but thank you anyways!

Comment: Can you please post the code of your form, and controller?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You're passing 'comment_path' in the form_for? Shouldn't this be the Comment.new, well @comment instance variable?

Comment: Does your new action have @comment = Comment.new?

Comment: When I do that, Rails raises an exception. When I delete the validation, the whole system works.

Comment: there is no new action. that is in another controller's show action

Answer (score 3):

It's a strong params thing. Permit :comments, then the attributes

```
params.require(:comments).permit(:rating, :body, :name, :game_id)
```

and, use form_for @comment, not comment_path

Comment: oh, @comment doesn't anymore

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to setup the form properly, I think the validation will work fine if the form posts as it should:

comments_controller.rb

```
def new
  @comment = Comment.new
end

def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  raise "It exploded into pieces!" unless @comment.save
end

private

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:rating, :body, :name, :game_id)
end
```

There we are changing the strong params to require the new comment key in params (which will be the result of the second change to the view below). I also moved this into a private function to clean this up.

So then in your view:

```
<% if @comments.count < 10 %>
    <%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :rating %><br>
        <%= f.number_field :rating %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :body %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This uses the form_for tag with the model instance which should, I think, solve this issue.

Comment: I just updated the answer with a bit more detail on the changes I made.

Comment: undefined method `comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f9a46f0fae0>:0x007f9a46f0eed8>         There is only #new in comments.

Comment: @avaragecoder Haven't you defined routes for comments?

Comment: Yes you need to add 'resources :comments, only: [:new, :create]' (no quotes) to your routes file. You can then add more methods to the only part as and when needed.

Comment: you see, my new function doesnt exist, comments are created in games#show, which goes to comments#create

Comment: OK now I get  it - in the games show controller action, initialise @comment = Comment.new there, and use that in the form_for as above

Comment: That was already there after you said it. You are saying this twice. Also, doing this doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

try this in the comment_controller.rb

> `@rating = params[:comment][:rating].to_i`

to make every input of the ratings to be converted as integer